# Quick sort and bubble sort give different results

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort, missing-data

I'm facing with a singular issue:
I have a big table which content is a lot of pair of numbers. I have to sort them in descending order. I wrote a BubbleSort procedure and works fine, but is very slow to do its job. So I used a QuickSort procedure and... Data inside of the array changes after the sort!
 
So I tried with a sample table, with similar dimensions and "easy-to-write" content, basically a cicle which assign to

```
    table[i][0]=i*3
```

and

```
    table[i][1]=i*5
```

and... Works fine.

The code used is the following:

```
typedef struct MATCHES {
    short size;
    unsigned short values[10000][2];
} MATCHES;



int partition(MATCHES **data, int left, int right, int pivot, int col){
        int temp;
        int i;
        int storeIndex = left;
        int pivotVal = (**data).values[pivot][col];
        (**data).values[pivot][col] = (**data).values[right][col];
        (**data).values[right][col] = pivotVal;

        for(i = left; i < right; i++){
            if ((**data).values[i][col] >= pivotVal){ //Change this to greater then and BOOM we're done
                temp = (**data).values[i][col];
                (**data).values[i][col] = (**data).values[storeIndex][col];
                (**data).values[storeIndex][col] = temp;
                storeIndex++;
            }
        }
        temp = (**data).values[storeIndex][col];
        (**data).values[storeIndex][col] = (**data).values[right][col];
        (**data).values[right][col] = temp;
        return storeIndex;
    }

void quickSort(MATCHES **vec, int left, int right, int col) {
    int r;
      if (right > left) {
        r = partition(vec, left, right, right+1/2, col);
        quickSort(vec, left, r - 1, col);
        quickSort(vec, r + 1, right, col);
      }
    }

void sorter(MATCHES *table) {
    quickSort(&table, 0, (*table).size-1, 0);
    quickSort(&table, 0, (*table).size-1, 1);
}


int main () {
    MATCHES table;
    table.size=10000;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<table.size; i++) {
        table.values[i][0]=i*3;
        table.values[i][1]=i*5;
    }
    printf("Unsorted\n");
    for (i=0; i<table.size; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n",table.values[i][0],table.values[i][1]);
    sorter(&table);
    printf("Sorted\n");
    for (i=0; i<table.size; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n",table.values[i][0],table.values[i][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

For doing another try, I took the data I need to sort into this program and result is again wrong.

I'll link the code, since is very long due the initialization vector.

http://pastebin.com/Ztwu6iUP

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
I found a partial solution. Instead of using quickSort, that is unstable, I used mergeSort. Now, when I sort the second time the table, for every duplicate (or three times the same value) on the second column, in the first I have data sorted in ascending order.
The code is the following:

```
void merge(MATCHES *v, int i1, int i2, int fine, int col, MATCHES *vout) {
    int i=i1, j=i2, k=i1;
    while (i<=i2-1 &&  j<=fine) {
        if ((*v).values[i][col]>(*v).values[j][col]) {
            (*vout).values[k][0]=(*v).values[i][0];
            (*vout).values[k][1]=(*v).values[i][1];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            (*vout).values[k][0]=(*v).values[j][0];
            (*vout).values[k][1]=(*v).values[j][1];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i<=i2-1){
        (*vout).values[k][0]=(*v).values[i][0];
        (*vout).values[k][1]=(*v).values[i][1];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j<=fine){
        (*vout).values[k][0]=(*v).values[j][0];
        (*vout).values[k][1]=(*v).values[j][1];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for (i=i1; i<=fine; i++) {
        (*v).values[i][0]=(*vout).values[i][0];
        (*v).values[i][1]=(*vout).values[i][1];
    }
}

void mergeSort(MATCHES *v, int iniz, int fine, int col, MATCHES *vout) {
    int mid;
    if(iniz<fine){
        mid=(fine+iniz)/2;
        mergeSort(v, iniz, mid, col, vout);
        mergeSort(v, mid+1, fine, col, vout);
        merge(v, iniz, mid+1, fine, col, vout);
    }
}
```

Any hint for this?

Comment: Why passing double reference to `table`? In fact you can pass it as is as the array will get there by reference anyway..

Comment: Quicksort is not a stable sort (i.e., the order of elements that compare equal is not necessarily the same before and after the sort). Bubble sort is stable. Could that be the problem?

Comment: What is the goal for this sort? You're sorting on the two columns separately. With a stable sort, the result would be values ordered by column 1 and then by column 0 (i.e., for equal values of column 1, items will be ordered by column 0). With an unstable sort, the result will be ordered by column 1 only.

Comment: @AndySchweig you're probably right. There is any sorting algorythm stable but faster than bubbleSort? By the way, is too long to explain, but I need that the second column be sorted in descending order. Everytime I have a two identical values on the second column, doing a previous sort on the other column gives me the descending order also for them.

Comment: Can you combine your various sort criteria into one comparison and just do one sort? That way, you could use any sorting algorithm.

Comment: I was thinking to write another procedure that checks, after the mergeSort, if there are some duplicate values (consequents) and bubbleSort them. Any hint for doing it in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use quicksort to get stability, you need to answer the following question.

```
Can I tell the difference between a1 and a2?
```

If a1 and a2 differ because they have a secondary field, then there is a 'stable' solution with quick sort.

If a1 and a2 differ because they were added at different times (a field which doesn't matter),  then the sort is unstable and will sometimes have a1 before a2 and sometimes after.

In your question, it is not clear if these numbers are linked

```
1,9
5,8
3,7
4,6
```

Should that go to :-

```
1,6
3,7
4,8
5,9
```

or

```
4,6
3,7
5,8
1,9
```

Are there 2 independent sorts? or is it a secondary field sort.

The merge code looks like a secondary field sort.

### Sort on a secondary field

To sort on a secondary field, the comparison needs to be like :-

```
int compare( Atype* lhs, Atype * rhs )
{
  if( lhs->field1 < rhs->field1 ) return -1;
  if( lhs->field1 > rhs->field1 ) return  1;

  if( lhs->field2 < rhs->field2 ) return -1;
  if( lhs->field2 > rhs->field2 ) return  1;

  /* more fields can be added here */
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of sorting columns independently

```
  quickSort(&table, 0, (*table).size-1, 0);
  quickSort(&table, 0, (*table).size-1, 1);
```

Try the following.
      Combining the sort into one go :-

```
  quickSort(&table, 0, (*table).size-1 );
```

Change the comparison to take base array

```
 int compare( short * lhs, short * rhs ) /* sort by 1 then 0 */
 {
  if( lhs[1] < rhs[1] ) return -1;
  if( lhs[1] > rhs[1] ) return  1;


  if( lhs[0] < rhs[0] ) return -1;
  if( lhs[0] > rhs[0] ) return  1;
  return 0;

 }
```

Partition becomes

```
int partition(MATCHES **data, int left, int right, int pivot, int col){
    int temp;
    int i;
    int storeIndex = left;
    short pivotVal[2];
    pivotVal[0] = (**data).values[pivot][0];
    pivotVal[1] = (**data).values[pivot][1];
     /* here you were jumbling pivot value - not keeping [0,1] together */
    (**data).values[pivot][0] = (**data).values[right][0];
    (**data).values[pivot][1] = (**data).values[right][1];
    (**data).values[right][0] = pivotVal[0];
    (**data).values[right][1] = pivotVal[1];

    for(i = left; i < right; i++){
        if ( compare( (**data).values[i] , pivotVal ) >= 0){ //Change this to greater then and BOOM we're done
            temp = (**data).values[i][0];
            (**data).values[i][0] = (**data).values[storeIndex][0];
            (**data).values[storeIndex][0] = temp;

            temp = (**data).values[i][1];
            (**data).values[i][1] = (**data).values[storeIndex][1];
            (**data).values[storeIndex][1] = temp;

            storeIndex++;
        }
    }
    temp = (**data).values[storeIndex][0];
    (**data).values[storeIndex][0] = (**data).values[right][0];
    (**data).values[right][0] = temp;

    temp = (**data).values[storeIndex][1];
    (**data).values[storeIndex][1] = (**data).values[right][1];
    (**data).values[right][1] = temp;

    return storeIndex;
}
```